# The Add Menu or the Shift-a Menu Is Stuck at Meshes

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to blender so this question may have an easy answer but, when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on my keyboard, instead of showing all the menus, it only shows the mesh menu
or the add menu where all of the primitive objects are stored.

I use the latest version of blender and I am hoping to get help from you guys.

[image: hotkey shift + A only shows meshes, instead of the add menu]

Answer (score 4):

You are in *Edit Mode*. In this mode you are modifying the underlying geometry of your object. You can only add or remove geometry, other object types are unsupported. Change to *Object Mode* with <kbd>TAB</kbd>  or in the drop down menu there :

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, I appreciate your help!